# Laravel custom time validation

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4

For my laravel 4.2 project i allow user to set an openingstime for they company. the format they give is 01:01  hours:minutes so the max value is 23:59 .
When validating i cant check for numbers or alpha, how should i validate if the input is like the format ? I guess i should make a custom validator, but i dont really understand the docs of laravel, and the stack posts give different solution but also dont seem to follow the docs. [link to the docs.](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: split on the `:`, then check the minutes/hours separately. e.g. `24:60` would be invalid no matter how you look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you find hard about the docs. Try this: (code untested)

```
Validator::extend('time', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    $parts = explode(':', $value);
    if(count($parts) > 2){
        return false;
    }
    $hours = $parts[0];
    $minutes = $parts[1];
    if($hours >= 0 && $hours < 24 && $minutes >= 0 && $minutes < 60 && is_numeric($hours) && is_numeric($minutes)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Where should i place the new validator?  in the control where i use it ? looks nice (but you forgot to check if there is a $parts[2] value 01:01:03 would be valid now right?

Comment: You can do this everywhere you want. If you have only one custom validator you can put it in `app/filters.php`. Otherwise I'd create a new file `app/validators.php` and require that at the bottom of `app/start/global.php`. And yes `01:01:01` would be valid. I'll update the answer.

Comment: ive changed it a bit like : if(is_numeric($hours) && $hours >= 0 && $hours < 24 && is_numeric($minutes) && $minutes >= 0 && $minutes < 60){ and removed the intval, else 0aaaa0:00 would be valid.

Comment: I was just about to suggest that ;)